# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for RoR file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My model is called Projects, which has a string filename and a string location. I have an upload form that's supposed to take a file as input, upload it to public/data/, and store the filename and path as a new Projects object. When I try to upload a file, I get "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for RoR file upload." The error is in line 86 of my controller file, which is "name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename"

View:

```
<%= form_tag( { :action => 'upload' }, :multipart => true ) %>
Upload file: <%= file_field( "form", "file" ) %>
<br />
<%= submit_tag( "Upload file" ) %>
```

Controller:

```
def upload 
    ### THE LINE BELOW IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
    name = params[:upload][:file].original_filename
    directory = "/public/data"
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload][:file].read) }
    @project = Project.new({:filename => name, :location => path})

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Can anyone guess what's wrong? I'm a RoR, and Ruby, novice.

Edit: I tried params[:form[:file]] instead of params[:upload][:file], and get the error "can't convert Symbol into Integer" on the same line.

Comment: check your params. params[:upload] is nil. Try params[:upload[file]] maybe ?

Comment: How do you mean? Sorry, this is my first rails application!

Comment: Try `params[:file].original_filename`, if that doesn't work, what's the html emitted to the browser for the file field?

Comment: Doesn't work; HTML is `<input id="form_file" name="form[file]" type="file">`. I tried `params[:form[:file]]` and got the error "can't convert Symbol into Integer" on the same line?

Comment: params[:form][:file] I guess.

Comment: try this, use paperclip- see blog - http://ruby-on-rails-dipak-panchal.blogspot.in/2012/10/paperclip-sample-app_4.html

Answer (score 0):

In you controller you are trying to get the file using params[:upload][:file], but in your form you created the name as **form**. So you need to change form to upload. So your code should be,

```
Upload file: <%= file_field( "upload", "file" ) %>
```