# Form upload "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, upload, controller

Delving into Rails' upload functionality and actually following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files) railsguide.

I use the following code for the **upload form**:

```
<%= form_tag({ action: :upload }, multipart: true) do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :picture %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

And this is my **upload method**:

```
def upload
    uploaded_io = params[:customer][:picture]     #erroneous line!!
    File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
      file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end
    flash[:notice] = "File uploaded successfully!"
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

I have marked the line which I believe is erroneous in the second code snippet. The upload method is just pasted from the railsguide and I adjusted the params array to [:customer].

When uploading a file I get this error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

It refers to the line I marked above.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721067/undefined-method-for-nilnilclass-for-ror-file-upload) other question, but I haven't figured out yet how that might help me.

What am I doing wrong? Is my form wrong or my controller method? Any help appreciated.

Comment: show us your `params` do this on you controller first line `params.inspect` and share the content of `params` with us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to

```
params[:picture]
```

Can always look at the logs to see how the request parameters hash is structured. When you use a form_for in rails, let's say on a customer object like below. You then get the fields as

```
[:customer][:field_name]
```

But since you just used the form_tag helper, it's not encased in another hash:

```
<%= form_for @customer do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :field_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried changing it to `params[:picture]`, but that didn't change anything. I would also like to do it without a model, just using form_tag.